# Pandas un-list while applying values to rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame as shown below:

```
in: df=pd.DataFrame(index=['A','B','C'], columns=['x','y'])

out:    x    y
    A  NaN  NaN
    B  NaN  NaN
    C  NaN  NaN
```

And I have a list as shown below

```
o = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
```

When I create a new column with the above list, the value that's put in the row is a list with the square brackets `[]`:

```
in: df["z"] = o

out:       x    y       z
      A  NaN  NaN  [1, 2]
      B  NaN  NaN  [3, 4]
      C  NaN  NaN  [5, 6]
```

I want the above data frame to look like the below(minus the square brackets):

```
          x    y       z
      A  NaN  NaN   1, 2
      B  NaN  NaN   3, 4
      C  NaN  NaN   5, 6
```

How do I acheive the above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, without writing some kind of custom class.  You can only put objects into a DataFrame.  The objects determine how they are displayed.  Lists display themselves with square brackets, so the square brackets are displayed for list values in the DataFrame.  There is no way to put lists inside the DataFrame without displaying the brackets; the brackets come along with being a list.  You could use tuples instead, but then your DataFrame will display with parentheses:

```
>>> x = [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
>>> df["z"] = x
>>> df
     x    y       z
A  NaN  NaN  (1, 2)
B  NaN  NaN  (3, 4)
C  NaN  NaN  (5, 6)
```

Of course, you could also put in strings containing a comma, but then your data are strings, so you can't access them as tuples or lists.

If you want to have an object in a DataFrame that displays itself a certain way, you will have to write your own class that uses `__repr__` to display itself the way you want, and then insert instances of that class in the DataFrame.  The DataFrame just stores objects; the way the objects are displayed is determined by those objects, not by the DataFrame (except that the DataFrame will cut off the display if it is too long).

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. I will try and represent elements of the list as a string and not a list in itself

Comment: @user1452759: Is there a reason you care about the display?  Usually it's more important to have the right types of data than to have them display in a particular way.

Comment: Well after I do this I want to push the data frame into mongodb. And I want the values in the "key:value" of the mongodb json object to be a string..and not a list.

Answer (score 0):

What you mean (without brackets) is actually a different data type.
Square brackets are lists, you need tuples:

```
in: df['z'] = [tuple(x) for x in o]

out:      x    y       z
       A  NaN  NaN  (1, 2)
       B  NaN  NaN  (3, 4)
       C  NaN  NaN  (5, 6)

      [3 rows x 3 columns]
```

Round brackets are essentially the same as no brackets in python